# ExpressJS: 'pg'(postgres driver) is not defined on routes/events.js, but it is in routes/index.js file

Tags: node.js, express

I have used the express generator plugin and I had all my routes generated on **routes/index.js** but I'm doing a refactor now and I'm putting all of the routes in it's respective router files. The thing is that the 'pg' module works fine if I put my code on the index.js :

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/dataDB';

router.use('/api/events', require('./events'))

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Now if I request a route from the **routes/events.js** file I get a **'pg'(postgres driver) not defined**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/dataDB';


//get all events from a user
router.get('/user/id/:id_user', function(req, res) {
.....
});


router.post('/friends/', function(req, res) {
```

........
    });

```
module.exports = router
```

And the app.js only includes the router/index.js file  ......How can I solve this?. The requests are getting to the router/events.js file correctly, but it's just not recognizing the 'pg' module require......Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was including

```
   var pg = require('pg');
```

in both routes/index.js and in routes/events.js

I removed that line from the index.js and left it only in event.js and now it works perfectly. That require is going in the model layer anyway, but now that I fixed it I would like to know why requiring something on one script and then requiring something on another script fails on express given the fact that I included express and the router in both files and those 2 lines didn't fail but the mentioned line did......